# Django Internationalization--without gettext

Tags: django, gettext

There is a way to make 2 language site by copying the same site, and changing the urls and templates without using gettext and standard internationalization steps.

Due to some sorts of errors my mac can't cope with gettext etc. Is there a simple way not to use gettext etc? I am thinking of copying the app and doing 2 sites one for en and one for my language. I would really appreciate it if you have also some videos that show how i can do that.

Thank you!